# Delete multiple records from store-EXTJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm aware that this question has been asked on stack-overflow multiple times, but I'm not able to fix mine using those answers.

I am trying to delete multiple records from a store and reload the store to see the list getting affected.

I tried using the `remove` fn on store, but it does not delete records for me.the `removeAt` fn works for me.

```
remove: function(records, listeners, ev) {
    var scope = this;
    ids = Ext.pluck(records, 'id');
    new test.MyComponent({
        scope: this,
        ids: ids,
        data: records[0],
        listeners: {
            submit: function(ids) {
                //ids is an array- 
                this.store.remove(this.store.find("id", ids)); //does not do anything
                this.store.removeAt(this.store.find("id", ids)); //this works for me
                this.store.remove(ids); //does not do anything as well
            }
        }
    }).show();
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You already have an array of records, can you just pass that to `remove`.

Comment: Is this what you're saying? this.store.remove(ids); I tried it and not working for me

Comment: No. `ids = Ext.pluck(records, 'id');` I am assuming there that `records` is an array of records. Why not just use that?

Comment: Make sure you call the store's sync method when you're done removing elements to make the UI reflect the changes

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure if I require to do that, coz the removeAt() removes the individual record instantly, only issue is with multiple deletion. are you saying this behaves differently for ,multiple deletion?

Comment: I dont' know if they're different. They shouldn't. In the past I've had to call sync regardless... But I got it. The thing is that the `find` method returns the index of the record in the store... that's why the `removeAt` works. What you need to do instead is call the `findRecord` method which returns the actual store record.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: yes the records is an array, but that still did not work for me.:(  this.store.remove(records);

Comment: Suggest you put together a test case then, not going to guess against a small snippet of code.

Comment: Can you create some fiddle to showcase this query ?